# Does a nmap scan against my own IP go past the firewall?

Tags: windows-7, security, firewall, nmap

I'm trying to secure my computer against local network attacks for when I'm at university or a LAN party.

Does running a `nmap` scan against my own IP go through the firewall or does it bypass the firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packets always pass the *client firewall*, but gets routed on your computer (these packets do not go outside the machine).

You can confirm it by using a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or iptables. Using iptables:

1. Temporary flush (remove) all firewall rules: `sudo iptables -F`
2. Add an rule for capturing local traffic (traffic that comes from the loopback adapter):

   ```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
   ```
3. Watch the number of packets hitting the rule:

   ```
   sudo watch -n1 iptables -vnL
   ```
4. Open a new terminal window and test whether the packets go outside or not:

   ```
   nmap [your-network-ip]
   ```
5. Check the command from #3, you'll see like 2000 hits (first column)
6. (optional) test for an other IP, e.g. `nmap 8.8.8.8`. No packets will be caught by the rule from #2.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using Windows 7...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: right. You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) then, the idea remanins the same. Listen on the loopback adapter and run nmap. (or do the opposite: run it on your ethernet/ wireless connection)

Comment: just to clarify by "the firewall" you mean a hardware firewall out on the university network yes ? Not the firewall of the actual machine your scanning ? i.e: Are you worried abuot the network admins getting annoyed at your scanning, or are you trying to check your local firewall works ?

Comment: @Sirex: By firewall, I mean the firewall on my machine, thus checking if it works.

Answer (score 3):

if you run it from the same machine as your scanning, no - it doesn't leave your machine. It does hit your local firewall rules though. This applies for both localhost interfaces and your Network card IPs.